# Matlab's diff in OpenCV

Tags: matlab, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I searched for a function in OpenCV that's similar for diff in matlab but I didn't find one, 
I actually want to implement the wls filter matlab's [code](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~danix/epd/wlsFilter.m) in OpenCV

Comment: `diff` is simply a filter with a kernel of `[-1 1]`.

Comment: I actually used it, cv::Mat Kernel = (cv::Mat_<float>(2, 1) << -1, 1);
 cv::filter2D(Image, L, -1, Kernel, cv::Point(-1, -1), 0.0, cv::BORDER_DEFAULT); results are quite different

Comment: Do not put updates in the comments. Edit your question to include your code and add sample input, your expected output, and the output you received. Please read how to post a [mcve].

Comment: You should also have a look at your `Kernel`. I don't think it's what you expect.

Comment: Did you still have a question, or did you fix it?

Comment: It isn't solved 100%, there're still couple of problems in there after I used the kernel above in two configurations for both diffx and diffy, 1- Shifted image, 2- Unanticipated periodic signal appeared in OpenCV

Comment: For the shift I saw that matlab is reducing the columns or rows in case of Y or X directions respectively, OpenCV doesn't, and for the signal appeared in the Y diff I'm still searching for its reason

Comment: Padding. OpenCV automatically pads the matrix so you'll have to figure out which row/column is the result of padding and remove it. The remainder should be the same as MATLAB's result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @beaker pointed out in the comments it's a [-1 1] Kernel, this is just the code to implement it

```
cv::Mat Kernely = (cv::Mat_<float>(2, 1) << -1, 1);
cv::Mat Kernelx = (cv::Mat_<float>(1, 2) << -1, 1);
cv::Mat dx, dy;
cv::filter2D(L, dy, -1, Kernely, cv::Point(-1, -1), 0.0, cv::BORDER_CONSTANT);
// Remove padding and take the abs of the output
dy = cv::Mat(dy, cv::Rect(0, 1, dy.cols, dy.rows - 1));
dy = cv::abs(dy);
cv::filter2D(L, dx, -1, Kernelx, cv::Point(-1, -1), 0.0, cv::BORDER_CONSTANT);
dx = cv::Mat(dx, cv::Rect(1, 0, dx.cols - 1, dx.rows));
dx = cv::abs(dx);
```

Comment: you should remove `dy = cv::abs(dy);` and `dx = cv::abs(dx);`, otherwise you will deviate considerably from the normal Matlab `diff()` function. Negative values are absolutely ok !